# How to get sub folder names of a directory that also contain dots in the name?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am trying to populate a stringlist with all the folder names inside a directory.

Below is an extract of how I was able to do this:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  SearchAttr: LongInt;
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SearchAttr := (faDirectory);

    if FindFirst(Directory + '\*.', SearchAttr, SR) = 0 then
    begin
      try
        repeat
          if (SR.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
          begin
            if (SR.Name <> '.') and (SR.Name <> '..') then
            begin
              SL.Add(Directory + SR.Name);
            end;
          end;
        until
          FindNext(Sr) <> 0;
        finally
          FindClose(SR);
        end;
      end;
    end;

    // do something with string list folder names      
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The parent folder which I was accessing contains 220 sub folders but the routine was only adding 216 folder names. After some comparing and debugging I noticed the 4 folder names which were not been added contained dots in the names.

To test I created a folder called "Test Folder" and inside I added 9 more new folders named:

> - Folder 1
> - Folder 2
> - Folder 3
> - Folder 4
> - Folder 5
> - Folder .6
> - Folder 7
> - F.O.L.D.E.R 8
> - Folder 9

When using "Test Folder" as the parent directory, it only adds the following sub folders:

> - Folder 1
> - Folder 2
> - Folder 3
> - Folder 4
> - Folder 5
> - Folder 7
> - Folder 9

I have been experimenting with `SR.Name <> '.'`, `SR.Name <> '..'` and `SR.Name[1] <> '.'` etc with no success.

How can I modify the code to allow folder names with dots in the name and add them to my stringlist?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks mystery downvoter appreciate it, at least give a reason if you feel the need to downvote.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a well-written question that meets all of the requirements.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, fortunately I am not overly concerned about how many upvotes or downvotes I get, my main purpose of using this site is to learn and grow as a developer and help others when possible. I just find it quite annoying when mystery users take it upon themselves to downvote other users questions without even leaving a reason or anything constructive. If a users question is bad then downvoters should at least give a valid reason as to why and at least present an opportunity for the person to edit there question etc rather than be left thinking what they have done wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the search string from `'*.'` to `'*'`

Your search string only matches objects with an empty extension. You want to match all objects whether or not they have an extension.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake,  I can't believe I missed that one, now I feel really stupid - I will just put it down as a bad day and move on ;)